# C# WPF XAML - How to show/import excel data on application?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, csv, xaml

I want to be able to import and read an excel file, by using an import button to open any excel/.csv file on my pc.

Where do i start? or are there any example code out there to get me along?

I have tried a few codes that i have found online, but none seem to be adequate.

Comment: Step **(1)** - add an "Import" button to your GUI; Step **(2)** - add some code to the click handler of that import button, to open a "File picker" dialog and allow you to pick an Excel file; Step **(3)** - once you've successfully selected an Excel file - use a library like EPPlus to read the contents of the Excel file and turn it into data for your system

Answer (score -1):

Save the Excel File as .csv

You can use `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToYourCsvFile)`

After this process you can run in a foreach loop each line. The item from the foreach you can split with `string[] values = item.Split(';')`

Now the values have the value of the line.

Hope this helps you